# Change Push Text - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to change push text once received after a specified time interval?

I mean i need to change the text of push in notification center. When it is first received it is like - "you have an opportunity" . After 1 hr it should change to - "you had an opportunity".

Is it possible? i've been through developer docs, i didn't find any relevant answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my point of view that's not possible with apple's push notifications. You will need to send a new notification.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the Notification Payload 'body' text or  specify a string as the value of alert or a dictionary as its value.

```
{
    "aps" : { "alert" : "Message received from Bob" },
    "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}

{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
            "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
        },
        "badge" : 5,
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per me, there is no way which I can think for this. If you want, you have to send another push notification from server side. Or there is one alternative, which is when you receive push notification, store body section in NSUserDefaults class and create one local notification with timeInterval like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelAllLocalNotifications];

// create a local notification
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

// customise and schedule it
notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.alertAction = @"Let's do this";
notification.alertBody = @"Here's a notification for you. This will happen every minute forever now.";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Change the alert Action and alertBody according to you.